# jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Not sure if you guys can assist this relates to the  jQuery-File-Upload code.
I am trying to pass through a value to create a folder name for my uploads.
Basically a query is executed in the include and a numeric value is returned to the variable $leaseId_file .  -The $leaseId_file variable becomes the folder name.
This part works fine. The folder is created and files are saved to the directory.
However, the uploaded files are not being listed when I refresh the page.
The following is the code I used in the file php/.index.php
- any help would be awesome.- Thanks.

```
            error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

            include_once('../../../_includes/get_leaseId_files.php'); // All this does is returns a value for $leaseId_file. This is the value I want for the directory.

            require('upload.class.php'); 

            class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {
                protected function get_user_id() {
                global $leaseId_file;

                 return $leaseId_file;

                }
            }


            $upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(array(
                'user_dirs' => true
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I'd suggest you first take a look at the various file upload plugins immediately available to you.  If you're trying to roll your own solution, I guarantee you're going to hit a lot of problems like this.  I figure though, since you're using jQuery to already make your life easier, why not apply the same logic to your file uploading script?

Here's a few I would suggest checking out if you're not convinced (in no particular order):

- [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) - Not jQuery specifically, but support for HTML5 and a number of fallbacks
- [Not a plugin, but a good tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)