# Cross domain file upload with header authentication

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, cross-domain

I need to upload a file to a third party from a client within the browser and I need to send an api token in the header. I need a general solution for new and old browsers.

this is what the curl would look like

```
curl -v -H "X-LLNW-Authorization: $TOKEN" \
-F uploadFile=@/tmp/wobble.txt \
-F directory=/testpost \
-F basename=wobble-004.txt https://api.lama.lldns.net/post/file
```

basename is not important.

I believe i am limited to what javascript can let me do here. I do not have access to the server.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: This needs more info. What do you mean by "API token in the header"? Where does it come from and where does it need to go using what method? What methods can you use for the upload, or does it not matter?

Comment: Are you aware that you can generally not send a POST request to another URL (search CORS on this site)?

Comment: right, so is there a javascript solution to this? Like a jquery ajax solution?

Comment: There's plenty of ways to use jQuery or native Javascript to upload a file, I just posted an answer about it actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199508/jquery-file-upload/13200006#13200006

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: A Cross-domain request will not work if you have custom headers. If you have custom headers, an OPTIONS request is automatically sent, to which the server has to reply with 200 OK, and then the actual POST is sent.
Since you have to authenticate with a custom header, you would have to change the server side to accept the OPTIONS request. I suspect you're out of luck.

Below is the code for the case with NO custom header, where cross-domain requests work:
Use HTML similar to this:

```
<form >
  <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload" onchange="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Use this Code

```
function uploadFile() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
  fd.append("directory","/testpost");
  fd.append("basename","wobble-004.txt");

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "https://api.lama.lldns.net/post/file", true);
  oReq.onreadystatechange = alert(status);
  oReq.send(fd);
}
```

See [this Mozilla blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) for more information.

Comment: At least recent Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari. Not sure about IE.

Comment: does this require any changes on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS with CORS you need to return a header from the options preflight request thats enumarates the list of accepted headers to be sent, can be any, but browser will only send custom headers included in that list.
Browser will only follow that OPTIONS indicated in the returned header.
Check CORS OPTIONS response standard.